# React Router v6 `useRouter` Hook with `basename` and Redirection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

The following code snippet explains how I define the application routes.

```
let routes = useRoutes([
    { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
    {
      path: 'users',
      element: <Users />,
      children: [
        { path: '/', element: <UsersIndex /> },
        { path: ':id', element: <UserProfile /> },
        { path: 'me', element: <OwnUserProfile /> },
      ]
    }
  ]);
```

I would like to have a `basename` defined for all available routes. So, every route needs to  have `/ui/` basename prepended. `'/'` should also be redirected to `'/ui/'`.

Previously, during the beta phase it was possible to define basename as following:

```
  const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes, { basename: 'ui' });
```

However, it is no longer working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the current API is still pretty similar.

[useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes)

> Type declaration
>
> ```
> declare function useRoutes(
>   routes: RouteObject[],
>   location?: Partial<Location> | string;
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
> ```

It still takes a string base location, but now instead of being a "configuration" object it's directly a [`Location`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location) or a string.

For reference, here's the `Location` type declaration:

> ```
> interface Location<S extends State = State> {
>   pathname: string;
>   search: string;
>   hash: string;
>   state: S;
>   key: string;
> }
> ```

So it seems you can either use a location partial and specify the `pathname` property, or a string.

```
const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes, { pathname: 'ui' });
const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes, 'ui');
```